# How to test my httpClient can close idled connections?

Tags: java, testing, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using http-client 4.3.x in my project. In order to close "idled" connections, I started a thread to monitor the connection pool and try to close connections which have been idled for 30s every one second.

The connectionManager:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = 
    new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
```

The thread to monitor it and close idled connections:

```
class ClosingIdleConnectionThread extends Thread {
    private final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager;
    private final int timeout;

    public ClosingIdleConnectionThread(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager, int timeout) {
        this.connectionManager = connectionManager;
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            connectionManager.closeIdleConnections(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now I have two problems:

1. Actually, I'm not sure what does "idled" connection means
2. I have to write some tests to make sure my code is working, but I don't know how to test it

Thanks for your help ~

Comment: It seems the while loop is never entered since `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` returns false if your is not interrupted.

Comment: Thanks for catching this bug!!! Just added `!` before that statement

Answer (score 2):

(1) A persistent connection is considered idle if it has not been leased from the pool. Idle for 5 seconds = has not been leased for 5 seconds.

(2) This is a tough one. I see two options here

- Use PowerMock, instrument SocketImpl abstract class and 'spy' on its #close method. Disclaimer: I have not tried it. It's just an idea and it may ***not*** work.
- Use Mockito or similar toolkit and spy on [PlainConnectionSocketFactory](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/socket/PlainConnectionSocketFactory.html) instance instead. Register Mockito enhanced implementation with the connection pool manager. Count how many times #connectSocket method has been called. If the method has been invoked upon new connection lease *after* a long period of inactivity, that basically means one of two things: the pool was either empty or idle connections were not in a re-usable state. It is not a perfect test, but it could be easier to implement given it does not require classloader magic of PowerMock.

Comment: If a connection has received all the response data and be returned to pool, will it still keep the connection to server?

Comment: Yes, it will. If a connection can be kept alive it will stay alive.